# Make div overflow out of its container

Tags: html, css

A very known question, yet - answers to similar questions do not solve my problem:
I need to locate a (inner) div (tooltip) out of its container (container).
The container is a template (aurelia FW) in the app.html.
The tooltip div is cut by its container. I use the best practice CSS properties, 
for the inner:

```
display: inline-table;
position: absolute;
padding: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
z-index: 100;
bottom: 125%;
left: 300%;
margin-left: -250%;
border: 1px solid black;
height: auto;
```

For the container (combination of 3 levels containers):

```
float: left;
margin-left: 18px;
width: 20%;
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

Even when making it overflow-y: scroll - I can't see the upper scroll sign.

**I'm aware this is problematic without adding the HTML code, but it's quite problematic including it (the html is built dynamically)**

Some idea for solving it (what other properties of the container/inner div are relevant)?

Comment: Could you show us CSS for the container?

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve this was to set the **position** property of the inner div with **fixed** value. Other properties may should have changed accordingly (but this is quite simple doing).